# Map a list into a type

Tags: haskell, databags

I am trying to transform a list ["a","b","c","c"] into a set in haskell, say: [("a",1),("b",1),("c",2)]. I am not trying to use maps. My function looks like so:

```
-- bagMyItem
bagMyItem :: Eq g => [g] -> Bag g -> Bag g
bagMyItem  (h:t) bag
     | h==q = (q,v+1):(listToBag t bag)  
     | null rBag = bag ++ [(h,1)]     
     | otherwise = (q,v):(listToBag (h:t) rBag)
     where ((q,v):rBag) = bag
```

Am I doing something wrong, or am I missing any case in this?

Comment: You should provide the type definition for `Bag`.

Comment: What should be the result of `bagMyItem ["a","b","a"]` ? Test your code to see if it's doing what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my suggestions for how to solve this:

Step 1: Initially I would write the functions with concrete types. When you make mistakes you'll get less cryptic error messages. Later you can go back and make the functions polymorphic.

Step 2: Let's choose `Char` as our concrete type. Write a function which bags a single `Char`:

```
type Bag g = [ (g,Int) ]

bagSingleItem :: Char -> Bag Char -> Bag Char
bagSingleItem c [] = ...
bagSingleItem c ( (d,v) : bag ) = ...
```

Step 3: Use this function to write one which bags a whole list of items:

```
bagItems :: [Char] -> Bag Char -> Bag Char
bagItems [] bag = ...
bagItems (c:cs) bag =  ... bagSingleItem ...
```

Step 4. Make your functions polymorphic. All you need to do is to change the type signatures of `bagSingleItem` and `bagItems` by replacing `Char` with a type variable and add the `Eq ...` constraint:

```
bagSingleItem :: Eq g => g -> Bag g -> Bag g
(definition remains the same)

bagItems :: Eq g => [g] -> Bag g -> Bag g
(definition remains the same)
```

Or - even better - remove the type signatures completely and have ghci tell you what they are with the `:t` command:

```
ghci> :t bagSingleItem
...
ghci> :t bagItems
...
```